# Getting type mismatch when looking up string in array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, types, mismatch

I have some code that pulls a string from a spreadsheet and looks up the string's index value inside an array.  I noticed if I keep my strings to 1 character, the code works fine.  If I actually try to run it looking up words, I get a type mismatch error, even though the string DEFINITELY exists inside the array.  Any help would be appreciated.  I've pasted a dummed-down version of the code below that still causes the same error.

I've tried dim-ing my array as variant or as string.  I've tried using white-space to make all strings in the array the same length.

```
Sub myArray_ISbroke()

    Dim arraysSuck: arraysSuck = Split("HI,HELLO,TEST1,TEST2,T3", ",")
    MsgBox Application.Match("HI", arraysSuck)
    MsgBox Application.Match("HELLO", arraysSuck)
    MsgBox Application.Match("TEST1", arraysSuck)
    MsgBox Application.Match("TEST2", arraysSuck)
    MsgBox Application.Match("T3", arraysSuck)

End Sub
```

I'd expect MSG boxes to come up with 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5.  I get an error 13 after '1'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the last parameter, the match type. See the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.match).

It says:

> If match_type is 1, Match finds the largest value that is less than or equal to lookup_value. Lookup_array must be placed in ascending order: ...-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, ..., A-Z, FALSE, TRUE.
>
> If match_type is 0, Match finds the first value that is exactly equal to lookup_value. Lookup_array can be in any order. Note that Match is case-insensitive.
>
> If match_type is -1, Match finds the smallest value that is greater than or equal to lookup_value. Lookup_array must be placed in descending order: TRUE, FALSE, Z-A, ...2, 1, 0, -1, -2, ..., and so on.
>
> If match_type is omitted, it is assumed to be 1.

Revised code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub UpdatedExample()

    Dim arraysSuck: arraysSuck = Split("HI,HELLO,TEST1,TEST2,T3", ",")
    MsgBox Application.Match("HI", arraysSuck, 0)
    MsgBox Application.Match("HELLO", arraysSuck, 0)
    MsgBox Application.Match("TEST1", arraysSuck, 0)
    MsgBox Application.Match("TEST2", arraysSuck, 0)
    MsgBox Application.Match("T3", arraysSuck, 0)

End Sub
```

Comment: That fixed the glitch, thanks!  I was surprised to see that the match_type being omitted caused this and don't really understand why.  Given there was an exact match inside the array, can you clue a clueless guy in as to why it didn't go for that the match vice casting an error?

Comment: I think the array wasn’t sorted. See the comments for match type I added